.NET MAUI XAML Binding TemplateSelector ViewModel Command
I'm new to .NET MAUI and XAML so I apologize in advance for any written/conceived "heresies".
I have a "Detail" XAML ContentPage to which I have associated a specific viewModel as BindingContext:
public partial class DetailPage : ContentPage
{
    private readonly DetailViewModel _viewModel;
    public DetailPage(DetailViewModel viewModel)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        _viewModel = viewModel;
        BindingContext = _viewModel;
    }
    private async void SaveRequested(object? sender, GenericAccount sensitive)
    {
        await _viewModel.SaveSensitive(sensitive);
    }
}

In XAML code, I have a CollectionView that renders an object with a type-based TemplateSelector:
<ResourceDictionary>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="GenericAccountDetailTemplate">
        <t:GenericAccountDetailTemplate IsFormValidChanged="IsFormValidChanged"
                                        SaveRequested="SaveRequested" />
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="EmailAccountDetailTemplate">
        <t:EmailAccountDetailTemplate />
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="CardDetailTemplate">
        <t:CardDetailTemplate />
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="SingleValueDetailTemplate">
        <t:SingleValueDetailTemplate />
    </DataTemplate>
    <h:SensitiveTemplateSelector x:Key="SensitiveTemplateSelector" 
                                GenericAccountTemplate="{StaticResource GenericAccountDetailTemplate}"
                                EmailAccountTemplate="{StaticResource EmailAccountDetailTemplate}"
                                CardTemplate="{StaticResource CardDetailTemplate}"
                                SingleValueTemplate="{StaticResource SingleValueDetailTemplate}" />
</ResourceDictionary>
...
<CollectionView Grid.Row="1"
                VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                BackgroundColor="#111"
                ItemsSource="{Binding Sensitives}"
                ItemTemplate="{StaticResource SensitiveTemplateSelector}" />

In the template, I have associated a specific viewModel where I expose a Command to be called:
public partial class GenericAccountValidationViewModel : ObservableValidator
{
    [RelayCommand]
    public void Save()
    {
    SaveRequested?.Invoke(this, Sensitive);
    }

    public event EventHandler<GenericAccount>? SaveRequested;

    public GenericAccountValidationViewModel(GenericAccount sensitive)
    { 
    Sensitive = sensitive;
    }
}

Template BindingContext and viewModel work correctly, but I cannot correctly bind the Command from the detail XAML code. I certainly made a bad binding in the instruction:
BindingContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource SensitiveTemplateSelector}}"
Command="{Binding SaveCommand}"

I'm not sure is it possible to implement this logic with a templateSelector anyway
I would like to make work the binding to the command I described without changing the architecture
I thank everyone in advance for your attention
Best regards

The RelayCommand would work better on your ContentPage, and, in your Template abstract it by declaring an ICommand bindable property.

What platform are you targeting on? And please also add some relevant code for GenericAccountDetailTemplate.
